# django images cannot be updated from defaults

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an image upload function in django. However, images cannot be uploaded. The page is redirected to successURL. I don't understand the cause.

The view is current because it uses multiple forms.

```
#view
def UserEdit(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    subform = forms.ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

    if all([form.is_valid(), subform.is_valid()]):
      user = form.save()
      profile = subform.save()
      return redirect('person:myaccount', username=request.user)

  else:
    form = forms.UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    subform = forms.ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

  return render(request, 'accounts/accounts_edit.html', {
    'form': form,
    'subform': subform,
  })
```

```
#form
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
#...

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = profile
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','birthday','image',)
```

```
#model
class profile(models.Model):
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/',default='profile/default.jpg')
```

```
#html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="text-center col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form }}
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ subform }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth btn btn-light">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/) before asking questions. The second sentence says "A view handling this form will receive the file data in **request.FILES**"

Comment: 'subform = forms.ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)'Rewritten to

Comment: I did it! Thank you very much.
I was saved.